# CAS software similar to Nspire on macOS 10.13

Tags: statistics, regression, symbolic-computation

**Last edit (2023-01-26):**

This question (and answer) has been closed as off-topic, even though the ***What to ask here*** for this site says:

> Software that mathematicians use (except Mathematica, which has its own Stack Exchange site).
> Source: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

### **I'm leaving this question/answer here because I really think it is useful for people who has never used an integrated CAS and equation typesetting editor.**

I started a math course yesterday and we have to use Nspire from Texas Instruments but my computer is too old to run the current Nspire version.

So far I have tried GNU Octave and GNU Maxima (wxMaxima). Octave does not do what I need and it seems that Maxima can not write math symbols. I need at least TeX support.

I found [a list on wikipedia of CAS tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_computer_algebra_systems), but it is very time consuming to install and try out all of them.

**What CAS tool, that runs on macOS 10.13, is most similar to Nspire?**

The math requirements are very modest - here is a list of things I need supported:

1. Equations
2. Graphs (I can also use [GeoGebra](https://www.geogebra.org/))
3. Statistics
4. Regressions
5. Save as PDF
6. Write math symbols

I'm currently looking into [GNU TeXmacs](https://www.texmacs.org/tmweb/home/welcome.en.html) for <strike>math symbols</strike> everything I need.

Answers from people with experience with Nspire is greatly appreciated!

For my first assignment, I got some examples of how my deliverables are suppose to look like in Nspire:

1. [image: Screen shot 1]*In Europe, except the UK, Switzerland and Liechtenstein, we use comma as decimal separator. The calculations does **not** need to support comma as decimal separator.*
2. [image: Screen shot 2]
3. [image: Screen shot 3]
4. [image: Screen shot 4 of text with a graph]

**EDIT:** @Henry explained to me how to write math symbols in wxMaxima, so I might not need another CAS program. But still, when the course advances I might find that it is too difficult to keep using wxMaxima, so Nspire alternatives are still appreciated.

Comment: I use wxMaxima: if I tell it `sqrt(r^2-x^2)` it will show $\sqrt{r^2-x^2}$ which I can highlight and right click (or use Edit from the menu bar): then "Copy" will give `sqrt(r^2-x^2)` as before while "Copy LaTeX" gives `\[\sqrt{{{r}^{2}}-{{x}^{2}}}\]`

Comment: Aha! So if I don't end with a `;` (semicolon), then I get the symbols. Thanks @Henry! I don't need TeX or LaTex, I only need to be able to write math symbols. I wrote TeX, because I could use TeX or similar, to write math symbols.

Comment: @Henry, is it possible to have math symbols in a text cell, in wxMaxima?

Comment: The question is whether you want to show results of CAS manipulations, or whether you want a quick LaTeX producer covering most of your points.  For the latter there are many options: since your course covers probability and regressions, you might want to look at RStudio: it will do most of your points including using [RMarkdown](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/) which can do LaTeX-type things

Comment: @Henry I've added some examples of what I'm suppose to deliver today. I will see if I can produce that with TeXmacs and if unsuccessful, I will try out RStudio. Please let me know if you know the examples are not something RStudio can produce. Thank you!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

So far I've manage to finish my first assignment with [TeXmacs](https://www.texmacs.org/tmweb/home/welcome.en.html) + [GNU Maxima](https://maxima.sourceforge.io/).

> [GNU Maxima](https://maxima.sourceforge.io/) will do the actual calculations, while [TeXmacs](https://www.texmacs.org/tmweb/home/welcome.en.html) will be the main editor.

[image: Screen shot showing math symbols in text and calculations]

*Screen shot showing math symbols in text and calculations.*

[GNU Maxima](https://maxima.sourceforge.io/) can be downloaded at https://sourceforge.net/projects/maxima/files/Maxima-MacOS/. I downloaded version 5.41.0 (the big green button) but it appears that the newest version, that is not made for [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/), is [version 5.43.0](https://sourceforge.net/projects/maxima/files/Maxima-MacOS/5.43.0-MacOSX/).

After downloading, you need to remove the Apple quarantine attribute because *Maxima-5.[version number].0-VTK-macOS.dmg* is not signed. You do that with the following command:

```
sudo xattr -d -r com.apple.quarantine Downloads/Maxima-5.43.0-VTK-macOS.dmg
```

*Above command will remove the quarantine attribute for Maxima version 5.43 .dmg file. The same command appears to work for all .dmg files.*

[TeXmacs](https://www.texmacs.org/tmweb/home/welcome.en.html) can be downloaded at https://www.texmacs.org/tmweb/download/macosx.en.html. I am using version 2.1.1.

All of the available functions and constants are described at https://maxima.sourceforge.io/docs/manual/maxima_singlepage.html.
I have also found a [cheat sheet which covers most calculator features](http://www.hippasus.com/resources/symmath/maximacalc.html), for [GNU Maxima](https://maxima.sourceforge.io/).

*Let me know if you are interested in how I made the assignment, in the screen shot above.*

*This answer is marked as a community wiki, so everyone can contribute with Nspire alternatives that can produce roughly equal content.*

Comment: @HarishChandraRajpoot can you please provide feedback to why you think my answer should be down voted and deleted, so I can improve my answers? Thank you!

Comment: @tortue can you please provide feedback to why you think my answer should be down voted and deleted, so I can improve my answers? Thank you! (sorry for the duplicate but I'm only allowed to `@` reference one person in each comment)

Answer (score 0):

I'd use Wolfram Mathematica. It's more than powerful enough to handle your needs, and offers $\LaTeX$ code output.

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately, Wolfram Mathematica does not run on my macOS 10.13 - https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/system-requirements.html I can not upgrade to a newer OS.